# How can we find the bar index of the candle with the lowest low?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

let us say we are looking at the past 100 candles and we want to find out which candle has the lowest low, we will use this function.

```
ta.lowest(source=low, length=100)
```

after finding the candle with the lowest low, how can i get its bar_index since this function only returns the lowest point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must write your own "lowest function" that returns both the bar_index and the lowest value.

You can do this, but you will have bugs if the same lowest value exists on two different bars, because it can return the wrong bar.

> after finding the candle with the lowest low, how can i get its bar_index since this function only returns the lowest point?

The best way I found was to write your own function that returns both the low_value and bar_index:

```
LowestValueAndBar(source, lenght) =>
    minValue = low //First just say this value was the lowest
    minIndex = bar_index //Same with bar_index
    
    //Loop e.g. 100 times and see if the other previous values are smaller. Then update the "minValue" and "minIndex"
    for i = 1 to lenght
        if source[i] < minValue
            minValue := source[i]
            minIndex := bar_index[i]
    [minValue, minIndex]
```

Code example:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Lowest Value And Bar", overlay = true)

LowestValueAndBar(source, lenght) =>
    minValue = low //First just say this value was the lowest
    minIndex = bar_index //Same with bar_index
    
    //Loop e.g. 100 times and see if the other previous values are smaller. Then update the "minValue" and "minIndex"
    for i = 1 to lenght
        if source[i] < minValue
            minValue := source[i]
            minIndex := bar_index[i]
    [minValue, minIndex]

[value, index] = LowestValueAndBar(low, 100)

label.new(index, value, text="Hello, world!", style=label.style_circle, size = size.tiny)
```

Comment: Thank you, this will work, thought there might be a built in function that does this.